# Can't "see" Gmail's "new look"?

Tags: gmail

I can't "see" Gmail's "new look". I have a poor monitor and my eyes are worse, so it all blends into one gigantic low-contrast wall of text.

I found that other skins will aleviate the problem with the light-grey on light-grey buttons (to some degree), but I am still stuck with the low contrast mail listing.

Eg, this is my problem:

[image: gmail low contrast mail listing]

**Question**

Is there a skin that provides higher-contrast alternating rows for the mail listing?

Or at least, a skin with higher contrast mail listing?

I'm open to any options, anything at all... Right now I'm considering a 3rd party mail client as my best option fix.

Comment: @AlEverett, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [Minimalist For Everything](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bmihblnpomgpjkfddepdpdafhhepdbek) which is a Chrome Extension.

Once installed click the extension and enable the Gmail Module.
Click `Options` on the Gmail Module and select the `Main` tab

This lets you set custom background colours for your email listing.

[image: Minimalist]

There are tons of other pre-defined settings that you can use to tinker with the Gmail look and feel.

As an added bonus, if you know any JavaScript & CSS you can create your own customisations and add them to the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "Compact" option under settings (a gear icon on the right top).